# Create an image of a Centos 7 machine

Tags: centos

I am looking for a way to take an image of a metal server running Centos 7 with various disks and mount it to a virtual machine using hyper-v on Windows Server 2019. This is required to make a backup.

I have tried G4L (Ghost) but unfortunately hit a dead end after installing all required applications like mysql etc.

I was able to create a .iso of one of the disks to an SMB share on our Windows server using dd command but we would require all disks.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did not understand the reason behind this setup, but you can try Clonezilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use software like `clonezilla`.

Download the ISO image from the official website https://clonezilla.org/

Comment: Hi Maruscya, thanks for your feedback. I have attempted to pull a clone of the disks using CloneZilla, unfortunately it seems to auto exclude any Raid Arrays in the available sources. Do you know of any way to obtain a clone of disks in a raid array?

Comment: IMHO the distro can't recognize your hardware. Try to load the driver driver manually.